# C++ Dealing with 'struct' and Strings

Tags: c++, struct

I have A problem in my C++ Code , I want to add 'n' number of Students with there Each Date , but I have an error when I Compare with if , here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Address
{
char city[20];
char street[20];    
};
struct University
{
char name1[20],name2[20],name3[20]; 
};
struct student 
{   
char name[20];
char degree[20];
University un;
Address add;
};

using namespace std;
int main (){

    student st[20];
    int n,i,j;
    do{cin>>n;}while(n<=0 || n>20);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<" Name Of student  "<<i+1<<"\n";
        cin>>st[i].name;

        cout<<" Degree Of student  "<<i+1<<"\n";
        cin>>st[i].degree;

        cout<<"   University 1 \n";
        cin>>st[i].un.name1;
        cout<<"   University 2 \n";
        cin>>st[i].un.name2;
        cout<<"   University 3 \n";
        cin>>st[i].un.name3;

        cout<<" Enter The City Of student  "<<i+1<<"\n";
        cin>>st[i].add.city;

        cout<<" Enter The Street Of student  "<<i+1<<"\n";
        cin>>st[i].add.street;

        cout<<"\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\n";

    }   

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(st[i].degree == "phD")
        cout<<st[i].name<<"  is  OK";

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So , I want To Check if the Student Has "phD" Then Output his name , But I get An Error , there is not output after the Date inputed , Why ? And When I change the date type of "`degree`" to `string` then I get Another Error in the `if` Say (is not a member of 'student').But I Really Want to do it With `char` , Can Help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strcmp` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare `char` strings

like:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(strcmp(st[i].degree,"phD") == 0)
        cout<<st[i].name<<"  is  OK";
```

or

IF you wanna use string in struct you can change your code like this :

```
struct student 
{   
char name[20];
string degree;
University un;
Address add;
};
```

then your for loop will remain same

Comment: thanks , but should I use A Function?Imean Not Done Without function

Comment: 0-terminated char strings please.

Comment: Unless you have specific reason to reinvent the wheel (aka school): Yes, use standard functions.

Comment: @user3457718 this is a standard function in `string.h` please refer http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: @user3457718 if you want to use string in struct I edited my answer above

Answer (score 1):

For members like `char city[20];`, you should instead consider the `std::string` type.  It provides the equality operator that you use in your comparison (`==`) and several other features.